# Reading multiple lines from a File in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, file

I have a text file with data that I want to read in Python. The file following data:

```
nodCoord = 0 0 0 0.5 0 1 0.5 0 0.5 1
1 0 1 0.5 1 1 1.5 0 1.5 1
2 0 2 0.5 2 1
# Element data: element type, material, connectivities
elCon = QUAD8 1 1 4 6 7 8 5 3 2
```

Now I have to read the "nodCoord =" line and all the lines below it which are starting with numbers into an array of numbers, say "coordinates", but I don't know how many lines there will be. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Read the lines as far as they satisfy your conditions.

```
def extract_lines(self, file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('nodCoord'):
                line = line.split('=')[1] # if you want to exclude the nodCoord 
                yield line
                continue
                while True:
                    if line[0].isdigit():
                        yield line
                    else:
                        break
```

This will give you an iterator of intended lines that you can then parse into an array.

Also note that this will give you every set of lines that starts with `nodCoord` and follows with integers. If you're not interested in rest of these lines or if there's no more of these lines in your file you can put a `break` in `for` loop after the inner codes.